# Delphi Android app parse error

Tags: android, delphi

I have an Android application that I created with Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

When I install it on my phone, I get a "parse error" message.

[image: error]

The strange is other apps work perfectly.

The other strange thing is, I can extract the APK file onto my computer, but when I try to view the APK on my phone, using APKViewer, I get a parse error as well.

How can I figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Obviously, the APK is corrupted. Did you try recompiling it?  If you continue to have the problem, please file a bug report with Embarcadero using [Quality Portal](http://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: Yes, I tried to recompile many times. I tried ti clean all and build all process but nothing changed. I have reinstall the whole Rad Studio but nothing change. Before I used an other virtual computer but I had to move to an other one. This project worked well in the previous virtual computer but now it does not work on the new one. My other project is works well on my new virtual computer.

Comment: I have created a brand new project and I have copied the all source code (methods, variables, ect.) to the new project. Now I can to install my application on my Android phone but when I want start it I get "Error “validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)" error message. What can I do with it? Do not forget. I work under Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

Comment: Did you, by chance, mod your device with a custom screen DPI?

Comment: My phone is not rooted. I cannot change the DPI. The font size is normal.